# The number of non-zero diagonal matrices of order 3 satisfying $A^2=A$ is

Tags: matrices

$A^2=A$ is an idempotent matrix so I presumed that the total number of such matrices will be infinitely many but the answer says that there are only $7$ of them possible. Please tell me the reason for that.

Comment: The key word is "diagonal" here.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if a diagonal matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0&0\\0&a_2&0\\0&0&a_3\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $A^2=A$, then it follows that $a_j^2=a_j$ for $j=1,2,3$. How many choices are there for each of $a_1,a_2,a_3$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider  $A=dig(d_1,d_2,....,d_n)$, where $d_i$ are diagonal entries $\forall i$. Then $A^2=dig(d^2_1,d^2_2,....,d^2_n).$

Since $A$ is Idempotent Matrix of order $n$. Then $A^2=A$ which implies that $d^2_i=d_i$. Which implies that $d^2_i-d_i=0\implies d_i(d_i-1)=0.$
Thus either $d_i=0 \quad or\quad 1\forall i.$

Thus we have two choices for each diagonal entries. Hence we have $2^n$-diagonal Matrices of order-$n$ which are Idempotent.

In your case here $n=3$ and you are asking for non-zero diagonal matrices. Hence $2^3-1=7.$